# GitHub action for storing multiple docker images in multiple ECR repositories

Tags: docker, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I want build frontend backend and nginx docker images for the repositories on ECR, each time I push into GitHub.
[Here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-ecr) looks like it just takes the whole GitHub repository for it, so it doesn't allow me to split it into 3 different ECR repositories. Couldn't find an example for it anywhere, is it possible?

Comment: It looks like you could follow the example here: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/push-multi-registries.md and log in to multiple ECR registries instead of Dockerhub & GitHub Container Registry.

Comment: thank you for the example, also made me realize that my actual question is, if I can split 1 GitHub repository into 3 different images, or maybe I have to have 3 different GitHub repositories for that

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you add three different names as `tag`'s in the `build-and-push` action, it should push 3 separate, but identical, images. Untested, but give it a shot.